# Google Map Multiple Map with Multiple Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am creating a simple location plan, so basically each google map will have a different location with a different marker.

So let's say googlemap2 = coordinate A and googlemap5 = coordinate B, i need each element to have a marker that hits and center in coordinate A and B (separately so that coordinate B marker will never appear in googlemap2 vice versa)

so far my code is as so

```
var map;
var map2;

function initialize(condition) {

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------- TTDI 
if(document.getElementById('googlemap2') !== null){
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('googlemap2');
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(3.140425, 101.632005);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, mapOptions);
    TestMarker(myLatlng, map);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------- CHERAS
if(document.getElementById('googlemap5') !== null){
    var map_canvas2 = document.getElementById('googlemap5');
    var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(3.140425, 99.632004);
    var mapOptions2 = {
        center: myLatlng2,
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas2, mapOptions2);
    TestMarker(myLatlng2, map2);
}


}


// Testing the addMarker function
function TestMarker(x,y) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: x,
        map: y
    });
}
```

basically it created what i want, just an annoying part where it always center on the first element, so lets say it centers on coordinate A for googlemap2, googlemap5 will have its marker, but the centering of the map will be off. Any help pls ?

Comment: Your code as posted works fine, creates one marker at the center of each map.  How are you adding the second marker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like the following to accomplish your goal and make the class more flexible.

```
var Atlas = (function () {

    Atlas = function (name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    Atlas.prototype = {
        constructMap: function (options) {
            var _this = this;
            this.map = new google.maps.Map(options.canvas, options.mapOptions);
        },

        addMarker: function (center) {
            var _this = this;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: center,
                map: _this.map
            });
        }
    }

    return Atlas;

})();

var mObj1 = {
    canvas: document.getElementById('map1'),
    mapOptions: {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(3.140425, 101.632005),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    },
}

var mObj2 = {
    canvas: document.getElementById('map2'),
    mapOptions: {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(3.140425, 99.632004),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
}

var atlas = new Atlas("atlas");

atlas.constructMap(mObj1);
atlas.addMarker(mObj1.mapOptions.center);
atlas.constructMap(mObj2);
atlas.addMarker(mObj2.mapOptions.center);
```

I've made a demo for you here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wKtmg/

Good Luck!

Comment: lovely! exactly what i needed!